# PHP Combine keys from different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this

```
"name" => array:3 [
    1 => "Hello"
    4 => "Test"
    21 => "Test2"
  ]
"runkm" => array:3 [
    1 => "100.00"
    4 => "1000.00"
    21 => "2000.00"
  ]
"active" => array:3 [
    1 => "1"
    4 => "0"
    21 => "0"
  ]
```

Can i somehow combine the matching keys with a PHP function so that the array would look like this instead

```
1 => array:3 [
    name => "Hello"
    runkm => "100.00"
    active => "1"
  ]
4 => array:3 [
    name => "Test"
    runkm => "1000.00"
    active => "0"
  ]
21 => array:3 [
    name => "Test2"
    runkm => "2000.00"
    active => "0"
  ]
```

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers guys. What i was really looking for was a PHP built in function for this, which i probably should have been more clear about.

Comment: if this came from a form, might as well group the name attribute from there, no more conversions needed, if not, a `foreach` should suffice

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArr=array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
     $newArr[$key]=>array(
                'name'  =>$value[$key];
                'runkm' =>$array2[$key];
                'active'=>$array3[$key];
                 );
}
```

this is how you make a new array and then print the $newArr and check you get what you want or not? Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$resultarr = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($sourcearr['name']);$i++) {
    $resultarr[] = array('name'=>$sourcearr['name'][$i], 'runkm'=>$sourcearr['runkm'][$i], 'active'=>$sourcearr['active'][$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well. And also, doesn't use hard coded keys.

```
<?php
    $arr = [
        "name" => [
            1 => "Hello",
            4 => "Test",
            21 => "Test2"
        ],
        "runkm" => [
            1 => "100.00",
            4 => "1000.00",
            21 => "2000.00"
        ],
        "active" => [
            1 => "1",
            4 => "0",
            21 => "0"
        ]
    ];

    // Pass the array to this function
    function extractData($arr){
        $newarr = array();
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            foreach($value as $k => $v) {
                if(!isset($newarr[$k]))
                    $newarr[$k] = array();
                $newarr[$k][$key] = $v;
            }
        }
        return $newarr;
    }

    print_r(extractData($arr));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a function that does that in PHP but maybe you can try this

```
$arr1 = array(
   "name" => array(
        1 => "hello",
        4 => "test",
       21 => "test2",
    ),
   "runKm" => array(
        1 => "100",
        4 => "200",
        21 => "300",
    ),
  "active" => array(
        1 => "1",
        4 => "0",
        21 => "0",
        ),
    );

 // declare another that will hold the new structure of the array
 $nArr = array();
 foreach($arr1 as $key => $val) {
     foreach($val as $sub_key => $sub_val) {
        $nArr[$sub_key][$key] = $sub_val;
    }
 }
```

what this does is simply loop thru each array and its values and assign it to another array which is the **$nArr**. I hope it helps.